# Why did Rickon run straight? [S06E09]

Tags: game-of-thrones

> Why were Rickon's final moments written this way? Why didn't he run randomly?

Conditioning (specifically for the fight) by Ramsay? Fear clouding his thinking?

Comment: There is no possible answer to this besides speculation. You might also ask why Jon was so dumb as to fall straight into Ramsay's trap, despite Sansa saying that he should not do what Ramsay wanted. Jon did not deserve that rescue.

Comment: Conditioning by Ramsay seems like an odd hypothesis. Seems like weird conditioning - to run straight. Fear clouding his thinking, on the other hand, seems like an obvious answer. No?

Comment: Jon's charge was not a rage-charge at Ramsey, IMO.  When trying to get Rickon, he found himself in the middle of archer range.  It seemed to me that, having been lured out there, forward was where he was herded by Ramsey.

Comment: "Why did character X did Y?" Uh, because they did. What else is there to know?

Comment: "randomly"? Because [humans are bad at random behavior](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/79287/104607).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263881/is-running-in-a-zigzag-helpful-in-avoiding-being-shot-by-an-arrow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ender's Game aside, Children are not always the best at coming up with combat survival strategies on the fly, particularly when they're scared for their own life.

While zig-zagging may well have been a good strategy, I don't think it needs any explanation for why he didn't do it.  He ran straight because he knew that he'd be safe when he reached the other side, he knew that every step he took in that direction it would be a step farther away from the people aiming at him, and maybe, he just hoped that the person shooting arrows at him wasn't trying to hit, but just trying to scare him into going as fast as he could (in which case, sudden erratic movements could get an arrow inside of him from someone who was trying to just get one near him).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263881/is-running-in-a-zigzag-helpful-in-avoiding-being-shot-by-an-arrow

Answer (score 6):

Probably because they don't have TVs where a young man might learn serpentine evasion techniques.

Other than that, with Ramsey missing the initial shots, a young boy might think that it's because he was actually missing, and would think that the ability to hit the kill shot would diminish with distance, not get better.  So, since Ramsey is "unable" to hit him early on, the idea that maximizing distance would make the chances of getting hit less and also decrease the number of opportunities he'd have to taking shots before his half-brother could scoop him up and get him completely out of arrow range.

Now, from observing his hunting, and also seeing (later) the shot through the eye of the wildling giant, we know that Ramsay Bolton is a truly exceptional archer, and was toying with him, but our knowledge, as a viewer, is something Rickon would not have.

I was thinking that Jon Snow should have used the arrow flight time and his ability to see where Ramsay was aiming to yell evasive instructions (stop, left, right, duck), but, again, that's from the easy perspective of my couch, not reacting in the heat of the moment on the field.  Would it be realistic to think that Jon Snow contemplated that kind of rare, unforseen scenario in advance?  Or that Rickon might have?  You see him hesitate, at first, as if he was thinking things over, but the fear of the threat of Ramsay driving an arrow into him, partially because of Ramsay's goading/threatening, caused him to run for it, full-tilt.

We can be pedantic about it, but why?  It was for increased dramatic effect, even if we pretty much knew what the outcome would be.  If we want to be picky, we could have had Ramsay shoot him down with the first arrow before he got 20 feet away, but that would have made for crappy TV.

Comment: "Probably because they don't have TVs where a young man might learn serptentine evasion techniques."

I never once mentioned zig-zagging. Only running "randomly".

Comment: I never said you did.  Serpentine, as opposed to "straight."  I wasn't mocking the question.  Watching the Peter Falk/Alan Arkin comedy movie "The In-Laws" is where I heard about and learned the term "serpentine," which is why I mentioned it specifically.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263881/is-running-in-a-zigzag-helpful-in-avoiding-being-shot-by-an-arrow